# Traditional Footnotes

Tags: footnotes

I'd like to make footnotes in LaTeX that look a bit more traditional; that is, rather than breaking the line in the footer between two footnotes, I'd like LaTeX to simply add an indent where the last footnote left off and begin the new footnote there.

This would solve the problem I'm having with spacing; I need to cite various sections of the same work, and it is extremely important that I cite them as they are used.  However, this becomes very cumbersome, and can fill up to half a page with footnotes reading nothing but "Ibid. \S 7.2," for example.

I'm a bit new at all this, so please bear with me.